# How do I calculate the functional derivative of the EM action on the curved spacetime with respect to the metric?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, general-relativity, action

I am having trouble with computing the functional derivative with respect to the metric of the EM on a curved spacetime:

\begin{equation}
S:=\frac{1}{16\pi^2 G}\int R \sqrt{-g}\text{ }d^4x-\frac{1}{4}\int F^{\mu \nu}F_{\mu \nu}\sqrt{-g}\text{ }d^4x-\int \overline{\psi}( \gamma^\mu \nabla_\mu
-m+iq\gamma^\mu A_\mu)\psi \sqrt{-g}\text{ }d^4x:=S_1+S_2+S_3
\end{equation}

where $q$ is the charge and $m$ is the mass of the electron, $g$ is the determinant of the metric tensor $g_{\mu \nu}$ together with $\psi$ being the spinor. $R$ is the Ricci scalar.

$\gamma^\mu$ and $\nabla_\mu$ are the gamma matrices and the covariant derivative for the spinor on a curved spacetime, where the notion of spin connection and the frame fields are involved.

My questions are the followings:

1. How do I compute the functional derivatives $\frac{\delta S_1 }{\delta g_{\mu \nu}}$ and $\frac{\delta S_2 }{\delta g_{\mu \nu}}$? I think I need to manipulate $\sqrt{-g}$ somehow, together with $R$ and etc...but I cannot see how.
2. Do the covariant derivative $\nabla_\mu$ and the frame fields in $S_3$ depend on the metric tensor explicitly? I do not especially see how I can compute $\frac{\delta S_3 }{\delta g_{\mu \nu}}$.

In short, I would like to know how I can calculate
\begin{equation}
\frac{\delta S_1 }{\delta g_{\mu \nu}},\frac{\delta S_2 }{\delta g_{\mu \nu}}\text{ and }\frac{\delta S_3 }{\delta g_{\mu \nu}}\end{equation}.

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: You need to open up everything that depends on $g_{\mu\nu}$: for example, try writing $R$ in terms of purely $g_{\mu\nu}$ and its derivatives. Same thing for the metric determinant.

Comment: How about the last term $S_3$?

Comment: https://www.theoretical-physics.net/dev/relativity/fields.html This site might help you for $S_1$ and $S_2$.

Comment: Thank you. Could you also recommend me any reference on $S_3$ as well?

Comment: @Keith Well I don’t know it’s name so it’s kind of hard for me to look up…

Comment: For $S_3$ it's the same; your covariant derivative can be expanded in terms of Christoffel symbols and there's a dependence on metric and its derivatives. You might need to find out how to relate $\delta g_{\mu\nu}$ to $\delta g^{\mu\nu}$.